# Does jQuery encode special characters when using val('any text') on a Texfield, Textarea?

Tags: jquery, textarea, textfield, encode, htmlspecialchars

I'm confused about jQuerys `val` Function. It seems that it encode html special chars when set a value, but jQuerys Documentation tells nothing about.

Is this a Feature from jQuery or is it an internal Browser-Feature?

Comment: It appears that you've got two fairly unrelated questions here. If this is the case, you should post separately.

Comment: [.val()](http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.8.3/jQuery.fn.val)

Comment: Can you post code that reproduces that? I suspect you're serializing the nodes afterwards, maybe by calling `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HUm9s/1/)

No, jQuery does not encode html special chars when setting a value with `.val` on a textarea or text input field.

```
$("#d").val("&nbsp;!@#$%^&*()_+-=<>,./:';¿█");
$("#t").val("&nbsp;!@#$%^&*()_+-=<>,./:';¿█");
```